# remove duplicated lines with tcl

Tags: shell, tcl

Remove duplicated lines with tcl is very long.

so I want to use the short way with shell and then execute it with tcl :

> under tclsh

```
% exec sort -u file
```

but the file doesn't change

is sort  needs redirection ?
how can I do that  !

Answer (score 2):

`sort` command does not actually change the input file. To do so, use simple file redirection as

```
[dinesh@lab ~]$ tclsh
% cat input
o
a
u
e
i
% exec sort -u input > output
% cat output
a
e
i
o
u
%
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement that in Tcl, I'd use [tcllib's `fileutil` module](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html)

```
package require fileutil
::fileutil::foreachLine line "file" {dict set lines $line 1}
set sorted_unique_lines [lsort [dict keys $lines]]
```

Most likely, this will be slower than calling out to `sort`

---

To write to the same file, and depending on your OS, there's a [`sponge` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sponge.1.html) from the `moreutils` package (sudo apt-get install moreutils)

```
exec sort -u file | sponge file
```